# JGraphT Dijkstra's algorithm has different inclusivity rules for directed and undirected graph

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I'm using JGraphT library with a fairly large graph and I'm converting my code from `DefaultUndirectedWeightedGraph` to `DefaultDirectedWeightedGraph` (I have generated dual edges for starters for every undirected edge). I use Dijkstra's algorithm to find shortest paths in my graph and I have encountered strange behavior - my tests blew up due to paths found being off by one node.

After a bit of research it turned out that JGraphT's Dijkstra drops source node and includes sink node for traversals of undirected graphs and contrarywise - it includes source node and drops sink node for traversals of directed graphs.

Here's an example:

```
given:
Directed:   A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F
Undirected: A <-> B <-> C <-> D <-> E <-> F
and:
source: A
sink:   E
Dijkstra's will yield:
for directed graph:   A, B, C, D
for undirected graph: B, C, D, E
```

Does anyone understand why does this happen?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'd love to, but this works fine in MCVE :( Problem shows up in proprietary dataset I have no permission to share (size of it would be prohibitive also). I'll try to debug this if it proves to be a bigger problem for us and will share findings then.